# Wordpress Staging to Live partial syncing

Tags: php, database, wordpress, synchronization

I've been doing some research on this and haven't been able to find many solutions that handle this. There is ofcourse the WordPress native exporting function, but I've had issues with this in the past and it's simply not accurate enough to push data updates on a staging site to a live site.

One solution I've come across is to not update the live site with content until changes have been finished on the staging site (staging site is for deving only, by me, and the live site is controlled by the client, so they can, and do, make updates to the live site). But this isn't an option with the latest update that is wanting to be done (74 posts as part of a custom post type will have a completely different backend for a completely new layout, as well as all the content being rewritten).

Another, which isn't really a solution, more of a 'buffer' as I like to think it, is to have a second staging alongside the first one. The first one has only demo information, to change all the code, the second is where all the content is kept, constantly in sync with the live site (or perhaps even using the same database but most likely not), and then putting all the changes on the second staging, and fixing all the problems that come up before putting it onto the live server.

The last one, which isn't a solution, is dropping the live database after taking a backup of it, uploading the staging database to the live site, after manually inputting all the data from the new stuff on the live site (this requires full knowledge of what the client has updated since changes had been made).

I've looked into several plugins to help with this, but pretty much none that I've seen have a 'partial sync' functionality integrated into it.

Would greatly appreciate any comments and advice on this problem.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and for now, and as far as I know there isn't any plugin or an easy solution for syncing content between WP installations.

My way here is to create a `dev` installation where I do my work using dummy (or old, provided by client) content and when I'm done, I copy it to `prev` install on my server. There, client inserts his contents and when he's done, I transfer it to his server.

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm wanting to do, but the client is adamant they want to update content on live only...

Comment: Well, you can tell him to publish content as "sketch", so it won't go live. If the coding isn't finished, you can also install WordPress on your client's server and put something like a blank theme, which will display blank page or a coming-soon-message, but admin area will be fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wordpress plugin which allows you to clone a live website with just two clicks. There is no need to export and import files or database entries. All operations are done completely in the background and creating a staging site only costs a few minutes. So you can run this plugin several times to sync the latest file and db changes on the live website with the staging site:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-staging/

After testing your changes on the staging site you still have to use FTP to copy your file changes back to the live site but you are save for testing all your changes on the test site first.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this tool so please let me know if you have any question about it.